# PHP move_uploaded_file function very picky

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io

I having trouble with the move_uploaded_file function on my website.

The whole idea is that in a form, i insert the title, description and a screenshot of a project. Everything is working just fine. It saves the title and description with an id and the creation date in a mysql database and moves the file to a folder on the server.

The problem however is that some files are transferred to folder and some aren't. The problem seems to be in the files, but i can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

It is not the filesize; i have files of 5/6MB that are placed in the folder without any problems, and i have files that are around 3MB that arent. The extension isn't the problem either, they are both .jpg.

Are there any other requirements that a .jpg file should meet, in order to be uploaded?

I'm 99% certain the problem isn't in my code, as it uploads some files without a problem, but here is my code anyway.

The HTML part:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Title*</h2>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
    <h2>Description*</h2>
    <textarea id="descr" name="descr" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
    <h2>Add file*</h2>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <h2><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Uploaden"></h2>
    <p id="requirements">Fields marked with * are required.</p>
</form>
```

And this is the PHP part:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$destination = "../uploadedfiles/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
    echo '<p id="succes">File has been uploaded</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p id="error">File has not been uploaded</p>';
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$descr = $_POST['descr'];
$name = ($_FILES['file']['name']);

include "../connect/connect.php";

if ($title == "" || $descr == "") {
    echo '<p id="error">Fill in the required fields</p>';
} else {

    $query = "INSERT INTO file(title, descr, name, created) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$descr}', '{$name}', NOW())";

    $upload = $connect->query($query);

    if ($upload) {
        echo '<p id="succes">Info is stored in database</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p id=error>Failed to store info in database</p>';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are the folder permissions set to?

Comment: i take it the file type isn't checked in the code above?

Comment: I am still working in localhost, and permissions are set to full control

Comment: Indeed Tom, i did this on purpose to allow png files, gif files and other imagetypes to be uploaded aswell

Comment: @PatrickBokhove By 'Some files are being transfered and some aren't' are these *files* of the same type? i.e. file extensions?

Comment: ahh ok, looks like your not checking for files with the same name. I take it each upload has a different name?

Comment: @Phorce Yes, both files are jpg.

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard Each filename has a different name indeed. I am the only person allowed to upload files, so that is no problem

Comment: Does any error shows up on Apache logs?

Comment: @Alfabravo Nope, no errors in the apache logs.

Comment: FYI, the files i am trying to upload are not read-only or anything. They are files i have full control of.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of stuff might be going wrong. move_uploaded_file is very pick and sometimes doesn't behave how it is documented. I had problems with it once and honestly, copy archive the same result in most cases if properly implemented.

- There are reports of lone filenames causing trouble. 249 chars on $destination seems to be the limit.
- not only upload_max_filesize must be set but also post_max_size
- utf-8 names might be a problem
- If you have problems where the uploaded file seems unaccessible, try to use copy() instead. There are reports of people not being able to find the file just after upload, move_uploaded_file just limits path over copy, the results are the same if you dont input any user var.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however the limit of chars is not the problem. The file i'm trying to upload is called DSC_0001. When i simply change the name to 1.jpg it doesnt work either. The upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are set to default, so 2MB and 8MB, but some 4MB items are uploaded without a problem. The files that are being uploaded are fully accessible. I am going to try copy and let you know.

Comment: Awesome, it did the trick. It still baffles me how it was able to upload 4MB files before, but im not going to hurt my brain trying to comprehend that. I'll add a check in my code to prevent exceeding the max file size.